# Swift UIViewController to another UIViewControllers (segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

i have a question, because I am beginner at swift iOS. I don't know how to make a segue from `UIViewController` to more `UiViewController`.
Example : i need to create 3 uiviewcontrollers and navigate to this view from is depends on time(morning,afternoon,night).
Schema is here.

```
     if(6:00-9:00)----->View
View if(12:00-15:00)----->View
     if(19:00-22:00)----->View
```

Any help please?

Comment: segue can only push fixed viewController. you need to check and push new view controller in code.

Comment: Use performSegueWithIdentifier ..... Set different identifiers and push your segues according to your needs

Comment: @Shruti yes i was try it but i cant make more action segues from one button

Comment: dont make segue from button....make a segue from UIview

Comment: Thats the problem , thanks , solved, firstly iam trying to create segue through navigationcontroller but its not effective in that way, thank u again

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make sure the four view controllers are in the storyboard. Then you need to make sure that there are three segues that go from the parent view controller to each of the children view controllers. Set the identifiers in story board for each segue to morningSegue, afternoonSegue, and eveningSegue.

Then you need to get the time:

```
func getTimeOfDay() -> String {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute

    if (hour > 18) 
         return "evening"
    if (hour > 12)
         return "afternoon"

    return "morning"
}
```

Now when the user presses on the button you can write something like this:

```
if (func getTimeOfDay() == "evening")
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("eveningSegue", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Manual Segues from Parent view to Child views with different Identifier name and use each segue name according to requirement. 
You can use button action to check if current time is morning , afternoon or night and call corresponding segue.